# replicating data in same dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replicate the data from the same dataframe when a certain condition is fulfilled.
Dataframe:

```
Hour,Wage
 1,15
 2,17
 4,20
 10,25 
 15,26
 16,30
 17,40
 19,15
```

I want to replicate the dataframe when  going through a loop and there is a difference greater than 4 in row.hour.

Expected Output:

```
Hour,Wage
    1,15
    2,17
    4,20
    10,25
    15,26
    16,30
    17,40
    19,15
    2,17
    4,20
```

i want to replicate the rows when the iterating through all the row and there is a difference greater than 4 in row.hour
row.hour[0] = 1
row.hour[1] = 2.here the difference between is 1 but in (row.hour[2]=4 and row,hour[3]=10).here the difference is 6 which is greater than 4.I want to replicate the data above of the index  where this condition(greater than 4) is fulfilled
I can replicate the data with `**df = pd.concat([df]*2, ignore_index=False)**`.but it does not replicate when i run it with if statement

I tried the code below but nothing is happening.

```
**for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
     if (df.iloc[i,0] - df.iloc[i+1,0]) > 4  :
            df = pd.concat([df]*2, ignore_index=False)**
```

Comment: Please, add more clarifications.

Comment: It is not very clear what you're looking to do.

Comment: there is no difference of 4 in the hour column in your example, also why does suddently hour 5 becomes 10? please explain a bit more as it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is exceuted, maybe it doesn't replace because value is `-6` instead of expected `+6`  - in `df.iloc[i,0] - df.iloc[i+1,0]` you calculate `4-10` instead of  `10-4` - If you would use `print( df.iloc[i,0] - df.iloc[i+1,0])` (or use debuger) then you would see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is: you want to compare 'Hour' values for two successive rows.
If the difference is > 4 you want to add the previous row to the DF.
If that is what you want try this:

Create a DF:

```
       j = pd.DataFrame({'Hour':[1, 2, 4,10,15,16,17,19],
              'Wage':[15,17,20,25,26,30,40,15]})
```

Define a function:

```
   def f1(d):
     dn = d.copy()
     for x in range(len(d)-2):
         if (abs(d.iloc[x+1].Hour - d.iloc[x+2].Hour) > 4):
            idx = x + 0.5
            dn.loc[idx] = d.iloc[x]['Hour'], d.iloc[x]['Wage']

     dn = dn.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
     return dn
```

Call the function passing your DF:

```
   nd = f1(j)


     Hour   Wage
    0   1   15
   1    2   17
   2    2   17
   3    4   20
   4    4   20
   5    10  25
   6    15  26
   7    16  30
   8    17  40
   9    19  15
```

Comment: Thanks,this is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: By any chance can i copy the data at the place where there is difference instead of at the end

Comment: I added new function to accommodate your request for inplace insert. please try the new function..

Comment: Did you try the modified function I posted for your new request?

Comment: yes it works but can you please explain what you did there i understood the previous code but this time i cant understand the working flow

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
if df.iloc[i,0] - df.iloc[i+1,0] > 4
```

you calculate `4-10` instead of `10-4` so you check `-6 > 4` instead of `6 > 4`

You have to replace items

```
if df.iloc[i+1,0] - df.iloc[i,0] > 4
```

or use `abs()` if you want to replicate in both situations - `> 4` and `< -4`

```
if abs(df.iloc[i+1,0] - df.iloc[i,0]) > 4
```

---

If you would use `print( df.iloc[i,0] - df.iloc[i+1,0])` (or debuger) the you would see it.